# Launch an application from AppleScript bundle

Tags: macos, applescript

I've created an AppleScript bundle - `main.app` from

```
on run
    set appAlias to POSIX path of (path to resource "MyApp.app")
    set cmnd to appAlias & "Contents/MacOs/MyApp &"

    display dialog "You're going to launch" & cmnd buttons {"Ok"}
    do shell script cmnd with administrator privileges
end run
```

`MyApp.app` resides in `main.app/Contents/Resources`

When I launch `main.app` it quits right after displaying dialog and asking `username` and `password` without starting `MyApp.app`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

One problem could be if there are any spaces in the path, then essentially the path will be incorrect. Therefore you should always use "quoted form of" to ensure spaces and other path characters are accounted for properly. Try this...

```
on run
    set appAlias to POSIX path of (path to resource "MyApp.app")
    set cmnd to appAlias & "Contents/MacOs/MyApp"

    display dialog "You're going to launch" & cmnd buttons {"Ok"}
    do shell script (quoted form of cmnd & " &") with administrator privileges
end run
```

Also, I think you need to be certain of the name of the unix executable inside MyApp.app. Most applescript apps have "applet" inside instead of the name of the app. So double check that. You may need this instead...

```
set cmnd to appAlias & "Contents/MacOS/applet"
```

Comment: No, on MacOS "applet" is for applescript bundles. For other applicationname.app it is /Contents/MacOS/applicationname

Comment: Yes, I know that's why I said only to double check that you don't have a mistake there. Please still take my suggestion of using "quoted form of" in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
on run
    set appAlias to POSIX path of (path to resource "MyApp.app")
    display dialog "You're going to launch" & appAlias buttons {"Ok"}
    tell application "System Events" to open appAlias
end run
```

EDIT

```
on run
    set appAlias to POSIX path of (path to resource "MyApp.app")
    display dialog "You're going to launch" & appAlias buttons {"Ok"}
    do shell script "open " & quoted form of appAlias with administrator privileges
end run
```

Comment: It works but I need it launched with administrator privileges.

Comment: you script asks for privileges and launches the application, but my app can't create files in the restricted area (/Library/Application Support/Audio/) anyway. I found a mistake in my script which application works correctly with

Answer (score 0):

There was a silly mistake in my script. I need to write "MacOS" instead of "MacOs"
Here is the script which allows my application to create the files in the restricted area:

```
on run
    set appAlias to POSIX path of (path to resource "MyApp.app")
    set cmnd to appAlias & "Contents/MacOS/MyApp"

    display dialog "You're going to launch" & cmnd buttons {"Ok"}
    do shell script cmnd with administrator privileges
end run
```

Comment: As I remarked in my post, I would still put "quoted form of" in front of cmnd in the shell script. You may move main.app into a folder with a space in its name, so quoted form of will just make your script more robust.

Comment: @regulus6633, oh yes, agree